# Accesing Richtextbox from a class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to append text in my richtextbox which is called ConsoleText. It's not working very well. I'm using a property in my form to access the richtextbox in the Class.

It looks like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //Skipped the rest
    public string ACText
    {
        set 
        {
            ConsoleText.AppendText(value); 
        }
    }
```

Now from my class's constructor.

```
    public McDonalds(string email, string pass)
    {
        Form1 f = new Form1();
        f.ACText = "test";
    }
```

It's not showing any text in my richtextbox sadly. I know it works, because i can in the property use a messageBox and see that the value is passed into it.

Thanks in advance i really need help with this.

Comment: Where did u write the McDonalds function.. so means you are trying to Update the Ui from Different Classs. Correct.?

Comment: if you are trying to add plain text to a rtf you can simply use .text
and if you are trying to set some rtf in use the .rtf

Comment: @AkshayJoy -> It's a Constructor to the class McDonalds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Delegate in `Form1` Class binded method `ACText (string val)`, and Pass the `Delegate` to `McDonalds` Class. Fire the Delegate

```
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public delegate void RichTextBoxDelegate(string text);
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public void ACText(string s)
        {
            ConsoleText.AppendText(s);
        }

        // In Some Method Call MCDonald's form
        public void ShowMcDonalds()
        {
            RichTextBoxDelegate deleg = new RichTextBoxDelegate(ACText);
            MCdonalds ob = new McDonalds(deleg);
            ob.show();

        }
    }
}
```

Pass the deleg to McDonalds form

Just fire the Delagate

```
public McDonalds(RichTextBoxDelegate sp)
{
    Form1 f = new Form1();
    sp("This is Test");
}

deleg("Test value");    // form McDonald's Form
```

Comment: I'm not really good at delegates, What should i write in my McDonalds class? Writing all your lines in my form just give me this error:
A field initializer cannot reference the non-staic field, method or property windowsformsapplication10.form1.actext(string)

Can't really see how i can fire the delegate. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Calling `Form1 f = new Form1();` does not give you a reference to an *existing* form, it creates a *new* one with blank/default values in the form's controls.

HOW to solve this greatly depends on your design.  If you want to tie your class to that form implementation, our class needs either a reference to the form, a reference to the control, or the value of the control that you're interested in passed to it.

For example:

```
public McDonalds(string email, string pass, Form1 form)
{
    form.ACText = "test";
}
```

A cleaner solution would be to RETURN a value from your `McDonalds` class and let the FORM set the control value appropriately rather than tying your class to that form class.

Comment: It's says that form1 is a type, but used like a field, method or property. When i try to pass it into the constructor.

Comment: See my updated answer.  Note that passing the form through the constructor tightly couples your class to the `Form1` class, meaning you can't use your class WITHOUT passing it a `Form1`.  It's a _workable_ solution but won't be _reusable_.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [Singleton](https://www.dotnetperls.com/singleton):

> Singletons make having single instances easy. They allow for single allocations and instances of data. We review the singleton types. We see one of the fastest implementations. And we review other possibilities.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static Form1 instance = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        instance = this; //add this class to singleton
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public void Show(string Message)
    {
       MyConsole.Text = Message;
    }
```

---

another class:

```
        Form1.instance.Show("blah blah");
```