# C# listView on two window

Tags: c#, listview

I have a listView1 in Form1 and in Form2 a method which adds elements to listView1 of Form1.
I am getting an error that listView1 does not exist. How can I remove this error.
My code is

Form2:

```
    public static string s;
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        s = textBox1.Text;
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(DodajWindow.s);
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Please Use Delegate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045581/accesing-richtextbox-from-a-class/16045806#16045806

Comment: Do you have any sort of reference of `Form1` inside `Form2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this sample Code am using 2 Forms,

**Code for Form1**

```
public delegate void ListViewAddDelegate(string text);

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void AddItem(string item)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListViewAddDelegate Del = new ListViewAddDelegate(AddItem);
            Form2 ob = new Form2(Del);
            ob.Show();
        }
    }


}
```

**Code for Form2**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public ListViewAddDelegate deleg;
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public Form2(ListViewAddDelegate delegObj)
        {
            this.deleg = delegObj;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!textBox1.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                deleg(textBox1.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Text can not be emopty");
            }

        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more, how does this mechanism work? 
(I mean how 'delegate' works?)

Comment: In this Sample I created Delegate , in the Sense I have Created Functional Pointer, to use the Delegate  you need to bind with any Method which is having the same signature of Delegate. Please see the Dlegate type and Method type, when you created a Delagate Delagte Binded with method AddItem() in Form1 Class, then you Pass the Delegate Object to Form2. still the Method you hooked up is in form1, when you fire the Delegate in Form2, deleg(textBox1.Text); actually it executes the method AddItem in form1, thats why ListView is Updated. Please study more about Delgate and Events.

Comment: What imports You using the above example?

Comment: Hmy i have easy example with:
Form1 only with listView and button add.
How i click button add to open Form2.
In Form2 textBox1 and button save.
How i write word to textBox1 and click Save to 'word' with textBox1 save on my listView in Form1. How make this easy example?

Comment: this is waht I creted sample.. Code. If you want I will give the sample code http://www.sendspace.com/file/ib4tvd

Comment: Please let me know you want Any more details. http://www.sendspace.com/file/ib4tvd

Comment: Akshay Joy please look this: http://www.sendspace.com/file/wa4y9x
How you click "Dodaj" and write word and click "Dodaj", to not added on my listView, but you second click "Dodaj" and look on listView, this word is added on end que and first is "empty line" added. Do you know how to repair it?

Comment: I didn't get you waht you are trying to convey. I will fix that 3 line issue

Comment: As I want to add a new word, it does not add me to the list as the next elements, one element only adds empty and my word. How you will fix that 3 line issue? :O

Comment: Change the Property of ListView -> View - > List . Use List Property is View of ListView Properties

Comment: Hmy this, not work, becouse i need two columns (detals must be invisible)

Comment: Canu Please send the Screen of List to me.. so taht I can Update. Please send the only ListView Screenshot (Design Mode). send to mail akshayjoyinfo@gmail.com or Edit the Question with Image of ListView

Comment: Ok very thanks i think now this will be working so good, very thanks again. :)

Comment: If you get the Solution proper can u Upvote the Answer only if you are satisfy with the Answer

Comment: Akshay Joe please, look your e-mail.

Comment: Please check this http://www.sendspace.com/file/czpxft I have Updated with ur reuirement